# Text width in one sided documents?

Tags: margins, koma-script

Example:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=10pt, parskip=half, DIV=9]{scrartcl}
```

*How do I calculate text width?*

In particular: I understand that `DIV=9` specifies that the page is divided into nine stripes, but how many are used for the border, in case the document is single sided?

In the documentation I only found explanation for two sided documents.

I measured text width with a ruler, and it's about: 14cm

Comment: The width of the text block should be the same irrespective of whether you have a one-sided or a two-sided document. Hence, whatever explanations you may have found for two-sided documents should apply to one-sided documents as well.

Comment: @Mico Can you back up this claim? If so, that could make an answer.

Comment: Well, if you run the MWE provided by @AndreaL. both with and without the `twoside` document class option (or, if you will, the `oneside` document class option), you get a value for `\textwidth` of 398.33862pt either way. Doesn't this prove my claim that for a choice of `DIV=9`, the width of the text block doesn't depend on whether the document is set one-sided or two-sided?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DIV=n` method consists in considering the available paper area (binding correction removed) formed by *n*<sup>2</sup> equal smaller rectangles, by dividing both width and height by *n*. The upper horizontal stripe and the two lower ones make the upper and lower margin. Similarly the inner vertical stripe and the two outer ones make the inner and outer margins. However, when the `oneside` option is active, one fourth of the outer margin is transferred to the inner margin (so both are one and a half stripe wide). The upper and lower margins still follow the rule.

So, with `DIV=9` on A4 paper, we get a text width of 6 times 21/9 centimeters, that is 14 centimeters, as you found out.

The parameter `\oddsidemargin` turns out to be 27.31467pt that, added to 1 inch, give exactly 3.5 centimeters. The computations are a bit involved because they must take into account the one inch shift in both vertical and horizontal directions that DVI drivers (and pdfTeX too, for compatibility) always do when printing or previewing a document.

When the `twoside` option is active, instead, `\oddsidemargin` is –5.88022pt; adding 1 inch gives 2.33333 cm; the outer margin the double (4.66667 cm), making again for 14 cm textwidth.

Answer (score 5):

I think the most accurate measurement you can obtain is via the basic TeX primitive `\the` followed by the specific lenght *implicity* declared inside `\documentclass`; this command is used to get the value of a counter, eg. `\the\mylenght`. (that's why the `geometry` package has to do with appropriatley modifying those parameters!).

Here is the MiniMWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=10pt, parskip=half, DIV=9]{scrartcl}
%
\usepackage{calc}
%
\begin{document}
%
\the\textheight\\ % this is the HEIGHT of the space occupied by whole text
\the\textwidth    % this is the WIDTH  of the space occupied by whole text
%
\end{document}
```

Which yields:

> 574.0pt
>
> 398.33862pt

Using the appropriate conversion you can have exactly (with the appropriate significant figures, let me be a little more scientific):

> 20.17cm
>
> 14.000001cm

You can see that this is within the accuracy of your measurement.

Comment: `\the\numexpr \number\textwidth*3175/59203584\relax{} tenth of a millimeter`

Comment: the formula of my previous comment gives `1400`, and if computed exactly from the value `\number\textwidth` (its exact internal representation in scaled points) one obtains `1400.000141883302...` and if I compute from the value you give in points I obtain `1400.000131174761...`. So there must be some error in the computation giving `14.026cm`.

Comment: @jfbu I checked the [Wikibook article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Lengths), and here it says that `1cm=28.4pts`.

Comment: the exact correspondance is `2.54cm=72.27pts`.

Comment: @jfbu Ahh... Misleading Wikibooks, but I have to admit, I was too lazy to do the appropriate calculation (this make me feel to edit my answer and remove the "scientific" reference because now I don't *deserve* it...)

Comment: you havn't heard about `xintexpr` ;-)

Comment: To express the dimension in microns, use `\the\numexpr \number\mylength*79375/14800896\relax`.

Comment: The computations with `\numexpr` are accurate because intermediate multiplication is with 64bits.

Comment: @jfbu Maybe there is a reference on TeX by Topic, I'll have to point this on the "to do list" now that I'm curious.

Comment: TeX by Topic doesn't know about e-TeX. `texdoc etex`. Sorry, of course TeX by Topic must give some of the dimension conversion factors.

Comment: See `8.2.1 Units of measurement`

Comment: @jfbu Thanks, basically an entire world opens when `texdoc` is typed...`:-)`

Comment: or maybe it is the world which becomes smaller when one spends too much time with `TeX`, `LaTeX` and friends...

Comment: @jfbu Thanks to zillions of mantainers, writers, and users that are contributing to spread the knowledge; I think that your assumption is quite right.

Comment: @jfbu Answer edited, at least if the calculations are coherent, then I may re-enter the more "sciency" way of describing the integers; although @egreg did, as always, a great job on explaining the `DIV=(k)` method.

Comment: Thanks for showing a simple method to get page dimensions! Still, I accepted the answer by @egreg as it provides information concerning how KOMA-Script does the calculations.